# How to try catch an Exception in string format?

Tags: python, exception

Trying to `try` / `catch` an exception in string format function.

Anyone has an idea how to do this?

```
"Hi {var1}! Here is {var2} Test!".format(var1= getMessage(), var2=getAnotherMessage())
```

Is there a way to `try` / `catch` an exception in the **individual** `getMessage()` and `getAnotherMessage()` functions?

Comment: Store them in a local variable before doing the `.format()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using python 3.6 or higher, try something like this.

```
try:
    var1= getMessage()
except Exception:
    # do something
    pass
try:
    var2=getAnotherMessage()
except Exception:
    # do something else
    pass
result = f"Hi {var1}! Here is {var2} Test!"
```

Though this seems rather ugly to me and it only makes sense if you need different handling of the SAME exception for each of the two functions throwing them. Maybe that's more of a design issue then.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the try-except block for the individual function as the following

```
def getMessage():
    try:
        return "Nithin"
    except:
        raise Exception("Error in getMessage function")

def getAnotherMessage():
    try:
        return "Physics"
    except:
        raise Exception("Error in getAnotherMessage function")

print("Hi {}! Here is {} Test!".format(getMessage(), getAnotherMessage()))
```

Now if some exception occurs, it gets raised for the individual functions before we come into the formatting part.